# Parent/Child with EF6 child collection always null

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

When ever I pull a MyList object via EF, the parent is associated correctly but the Children collection is always null. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, pretty much every article shows to do it this way.

*Database*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyList] (
    [MyListId]     BIGINT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentMyListId] BIGINT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyList] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MyListId] ASC) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_MyList_MyList_MyListId] FOREIGN KEY (ParentMyListId) REFERENCES MyList(MyListId)
);
```

*Model*

```
public class MyList
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long MyListId { get; set; }
    public long? ParentMyListId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentMyListId")]
    public virtual List MyListParent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MyList> MyListChildren { get; set; }
}
```

*DBContext*

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base(Properties.Settings.Default.DbContext)
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<MyList> MyLists { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyList>()
        .ToTable("MyList", "dbo")
        .HasOptional(x => x.MyListParent)
        .WithMany(x => x.MyListChildren)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentMyListId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: is lazy loading enabled ?

Comment: As an aside, I recommend using C#'s `nameof` operator instead of hardcoding the string `"ParentMyListId"`, so you'd put `[ForeignKey( nameof( MyList.ParentMyListId ) )]` - for extra build-time safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with same structure in EF 6.1.3 version and it worked like charm. I added image of output and data present in db. The only thing that might stopped working if you disable loading in configuration. I hope it work for you please try my sample code.

```
  // Your entity class I added name property to show you the results 
   public class MyList
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long MyListId { get; set; }
        public long? ParentMyListId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ParentMyListId")]
        public virtual MyList MyListParent { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MyList> MyListChildren { get; set; }
    }       

     // DBContext please note no configuration properties set just default constructor 
     // you need t check here if you have set soemthing here 
       public class TestContext : DbContext
        {
            public TestContext()
                : base("name=TestConnection")
            {
            }               

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<MyList>()
                .ToTable("MyList", "dbo")
                .HasOptional(x => x.MyListParent)
                .WithMany(x => x.MyListChildren)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentMyListId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            }

            public virtual DbSet<MyList> Lists { get; set; }
        }
```

The console app to show result:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new TestContext())
        {

            // for testing to see al working 
            //this is important to read the entity first .
            var parent = ctx.Lists.ToList();

            foreach (var p in parent)
            {
                foreach (var child in p.MyListChildren)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(@"Parent Name {0}  has child with name {1}", p.Name, child.Name));
                }
            }

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Output of app and data in database ...

[image]

Comment: I'll have to do more troubleshooting I guess. Not sure why mine doesn't work.

Comment: plz share your dbcontext class

Comment: Update OP to include dbcontext

Comment: I can see you idsabled lazyloading then how you can get navigation properties . If you want then . Use something like this . ctx.Lists.Include("MyListChildren ").ToList();

Comment: try this Include("MyListChildren") before ToList() hope it will help you

Comment: @user3953989  
try this Include("MyListChildren") before ToList() hope it will help you

Comment: ahhhhh derp. That was it, I was just forgetting to Include the reference. Thanks so much for all the help. Just curious, is there a way to Include up to a certain level of children elements? I.e. MyList.Children[0].children[0].children[2] without doing Include("MyListChildren.MyListChildren.MyListChildren.MyListChildren")?

Comment: I think if you see it is already there if you debug then you may see data in different level .